How to allow withdraw of spl-tokens based on price growth
I am a beginner and I am learning about Solana development with anchor. I am trying to create a token vesting program that allows a user withdraw tokens based on price growth. For example, a user will be able to withdraw tokens only if the price has grown 10x. Now I can't figure out how to do this. There is no way to get token price data on chain especially for new tokens. So how would I find if I can release the tokens? I think if I pass price data from the client as arguments then it will be unsafe as client data can be tampered.
Note: I am using anchor.
Thanks a lot.

You'll need to have some sort of trusted oracle with the price information. You could use a dex market as the basis.

Is there any way to do this securely without using oracle? May be pass the price from the client as part of the withdraw transaction?

That's too easy to game unfortunately. "Price" is a function of on-chain markets or oracles, so you'll need to use one of them to get a price.

Any other option like just validating the price on with a script and then using a PDA with @solana/web3.js, send the tokens to the user. I think I would need to save the secret key in the script if I use this option. Is it doable?

Correct, you could also have a web service that validates prices in user transactions, and only signs if the price is "good". Then your program can validate that your key signed. This is pretty similar to running an oracle!

Thanks a lot for your comments John. Can we please connect somewhere as I have some more questions
